# C.H. Edwards "Advanced Calculus of Several Variables", Problem 3.5 of page 194

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, implicit-function-theorem

In C.H. Edward's *Advanced Calculus of Several Variables* in the Chapter III in Section 3 on *Inverse and Implicit Mapping Theorems* question #5 is given as follows:

> **3.5** Show that the equations
>   $$ \sin(x+z)+\log yz^2 = 0, \qquad e^{x+z}+yz=0 $$
>   implicitly define $z$ near $-1$ as a function of $(x,y)$ near $(1,1)$.

My trouble here is in understanding what is meant by the statement. If I am to consider the collection of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for which both $G_1(x,y,z)= \sin(x+z)+\log yz^2 = 0$  and $G_2(x,y,z)=e^{x+z}+yz=0$ then, if the Jacobian is rank two near $(1,1,-1)$ then we have two (independent) equations and three unknowns hence the implicit solution would have just one free parameter. That is, the implicit solution would seem to be a curve not a surface. Very well, for completeness, let us calculate the Jacobian:
$$ G'(x,y,z) = [\partial_xG|\partial_yG|\partial_zG] = 
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} \cos(x+z) & 1/y & \cos(x+z)+2/z \\
e^{x+z} & z & e^{x+z}+y \end{array}\right] $$
and evaluate at $(1,1,-1)$ for which clearly $G(1,1,-1)=(0,0)$
$$ G'(1,1,-1) =  
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 2 \end{array}\right] $$
It is clear to me that the matrix above has rank two. Moreover, we can apply the implicit mapping theorem to solve for $x,z$ as a functions of $y$, that is we could find $h_1,h_2$ functions for which $G(h_1(y),y,h_2(y))=(0,0)$ for $y$ near $1$. Or, we could solve for $x,y$ are functions of $z$, that is we could find $h_3,h_4$ such that $G(h_3(z),h_4(z),z)=(0,0)$ for $z$ near $-1$. Finally (thanks to Ted Shifrin's correction) we can also find solution exists for $z,y$ in terms of $x$ exists near $(1,1,-1)$.

In short, if I consider both equations at once, I don't see a surface parametrized by $x,y$ near $(1,1,-1)$.

**Question:** does Edwards intend us to consider the equations $G_1=0$ and $G_2=0$ separately? In that case, I can solve for two (distinct) surfaces implicitly given by $G_1(x,y,z)=0$ and $G_2(x,y,z)=0$ respective. The intersection of those surfaces would correspond to the curve which the implicit mapping theorem applied to $G = (G_1,G_2)$ revealed. Am I missing something here?

Comment: JamesS.Cook, sure. I looked, and (unsurprisingly) can't think of anything to add to @TedShifrin's answer (except, as you say, that it might be meant as two unrelated parts of the question).

Comment: James, your partials still aren't right!!

Comment: @TedShifrin Apparently I need to actually stop calculating in LaTeX... hopefully there correct now, I used a pencil and paper this time.

Comment: "$z$ is a function of $(x,y)$ near $p$" is consistent with either dimension of the local solution set, is it not?  In the case of a curve it would mean all $(x,y)$ on the curve near $p$.   And in both cases saying it is a function means some additional condition about $dz$ being a function of $(dx,dy)$ near the point.  It sounds like this is a terminology question.

Comment: @zyx: No. It's a question of how many "free" or "independent" variables we have (just like with systems of linear equations). Here there is only *one* independent variable, not two.

Comment: @TedShifrin, the statement of the book exercise is true no matter what the number of "free variables" (the dimension of the local solution set) is, except in special cases where that solution set is parallel to one of the coordinate axes/planes.  This is why it seems to be at heart a terminology question that leads to the computational question of finding the rank of the Jacobian at or near the point.

Comment: @xyz: No, the book is wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin, can you clarify whether your objection is to the terminology "$z$ is a function of $(x,y)$ near point $p$" (for a 1-dimensional submanifold of $(x,y,z)$ values, passing through $p$) or to something else in the exercise?

Comment: @zyx: The solution set is a $1$-dimensional manifold, so it cannot be represented as a graph of a function of two variables.

Comment: @TedShifrin, the problem with that interpretation of "$(x,y)$ near $p$" is that the equations are first assumed to hold (so that $z$ is related to the other variables, but this then relates $x$ and $y$ to each other) and then assumed to not hold (for $x$ and $y$). This is not consistent.  It would also say that, near the same point, $z$ is a function of $x$, and $z$ is a function of $y$, but $z$ is not a function of $(x,y)$. It seems far more natural here to take $x,y,z$ to be functions on the solution set of the equations, and then the statement in the book is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's clearly a typo in the question. My copy of the book is in my office, so I can't check it now. However, you did miscalculate the formulas for the partial derivatives. I get the Jacobian matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\,.$$
So since all three $2\times 2$ minors are nonzero, we can locally express this curve as a graph in any of the three ways.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I modified my post which suffered several unfortunate mistakes in the $z$-derivative. Incidentally, do you happen to know of any example where a system of equations usually supports a solution curve, but then in a certain domain, the rank of the defining Jacobian collapses and gives a surface. I think I can come up with an example, but perhaps you already know a good place to point me.

Comment: First, although it's the opposite of what you want, consider $f\colon\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$, $f(x,y,z) = (x^2+y^2)z$. Then depending on your initial point (not the origin), the level set $f=0$ is either a surface ($z=0$) or a line ($x=y=0$). Now, what happens if you try $f\colon\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$, $f(x,y,z) = (xz,yz)$ and look at $f=0$?

Comment: So, if I calculate correctly, which is debateable today, $f'(0,0,1)$ is rank two whereas $f'(1,0,0)$ is rank one. Therefore, level sets will be one-dimensional near $(0,0,1)$ and two-dimensional near $(1,0,0)$. Nice.